# How to open a new window or tab via javascript in windows phone 7 browser

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is it possible to open a new window or tab via `javascript` in `Windows Phone 7` browser?

`window.open` does not appear to be supported nor does `target='_blank'`.

Am I missing something here? This basic feature works just fine on iphone and android.
Any ideas on how I can get this working in Windows Phone 7?

Comment: In the browser settings, there's an option to 'Open links in a new tab'. I doubt that can be overriden by the app.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On Windows Phone 7 this is not possible programmatically. It's all in the users hand.

To cite a [Microsoft employee](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/51745797-0d3f-4792-8904-80fa7505799c):

> "A user can open a link in a new Tab by tapping and holding the link to
> get the context menu  but an anchor or scripts request to target a new
> window is ignored.
>
> There are several reasons for this:
>
> - Cross-window communications are not supported.
> - Windows Phone only has one instance of the
>   browser so new "windows" have to be opened as Tab's.
> - The browser experience is full screen so the user has no good visual cue that they
>   have moved to a new Tab unless they explicity request it.
> - Navigating "back" in a new Tab exits the browser which would be
>   confusing to the user if they did not know a new Tab was created."

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: great answer. Is there any information wether this is the same case for Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Is there a workaround to verify if a new window can be opened so a  fallback method can be used if not?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to add this feature for in-ap browser control, I can suggest you one way.

You have to inject a java-script on every webpage the browser control is able to load the page successfully. In the java-script use window.extern.notify to invoke the `ScriptNotify` function in your code behind. On the detection of the appropriate message create a new instance of browser control and add it to an array or list. Thereby you can emulate the new tab feature for in-app browser control.

the JS code to be injected may be like this `String NEW_TAB_FUNCTION = "window.open = function(__msg){window.external.notify('addnewtab');};";`

Which can be injected using `browser.InvokeScript("eval", NEW_TAB_FUNCTION);`

In ScriptNotify check for `addnewtab` (keep `IsScriptEnabled = True`)

```
    void WebBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value == "addnewtab")
        {   
            //do work here
        }
    }
```

Note that I have overridden the window.open function in the JS with a function which will be injected every time on a new webpage in order to get notified of user input.

Also note this works only for WebBrowser Control and not external browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I'm just dealing with the "external" browser.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround this issue is simple:

```
window.open
```

returns null if failed, so in that case I open it in the same window:

```
var win = window.open(href, '_blank');
    if(!win || win==null){
        window.location.href = href;
    }else{
        win.focus();     
    }
```

which is a good practice to have a fallback anyway...

Comment: Hey Tomer, This doesn't work in windows phone 10 Edge browser. Any idea?

Comment: @AshutoshJha I think it got to do with the window size. Look here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11026637/  and here:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_internet-insider_spartan-insiderplat_pc/windows-edge-does-not-open-the-new-window-directly/272c607a-253f-47a4-8ec7-4236d30940a1