# Test a mobile page Windows Phone 7 Browser

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, mobile-website, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am developing a mobile webpage for windows phone 7.

Please suggest me any emulator/simulator to test the page which occupies less memory, i try to install windows official emulator with the windows phone SDK, since it needs more system space, i dropped that plan.

is there any other alternative way to test the webpage in windows phone-7 browser?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test it on IE. If it works on IE it will work on mobile. For the mobile related specs you need to get hold of the emulator in the SDK or get a mobile phone device.

Comment: :Thanks. I tested in my desktop IE9 and IE8 it is working correctly.when i tested in emulator from my friend machine it is showing wrong result.what i want is simple: i want to open a link in new window/tab, but for me it always opening in same window in the window phone-7 IE9.If you could help me it will be great.

Comment: This is the link <a target="_blank" data-rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="http://www.google.com/"     class="ui-link">google SITE</a>

Comment: i don't know how new tabs code functions. But on a device, to open a link in new tab you hold the link and an option appears to open in new tab. apart from that I guess it depends on user settings too.

Comment: i read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201436/how-to-open-a-new-window-or-tab-via-javascript-in-windows-phone-7-browser, from this i understand that it is not possible to open the link in new tab. Please correct me if i am not correct.

Comment: even on that post i have posted an answer for inapp browser, but for IE its not possible as somebody there also has pointed out

Comment: correct you are. but i am sad that my requirement is to open the link in new tab when user click the link from ie browser.Thanks for ur help Milan.Anyhow IE should should change as like other browsers

Comment: ya i agree. But sadly IE wont change for now. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

i hope this page will be useful for you 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.92%29.aspx