# How to open a pop up in new tab

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In an mobile web application I am working on, I have an option to open a pop up from the parent page. To do this I use the Javascript `window.open` function.

On a Windows Phone (Nokia Lumia 900 running Phone 7.5) the pop up is opening in the same window instead of opening in new tab. In other devices (Android and iPhone) it works as expected.

How can I get Windows Phone to open the pop-up in a new tab?

Comment: You can't do this unfortunately.

See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201436/how-to-open-a-new-window-or-tab-via-javascript-in-windows-phone-7-browser