# Windows Phone 8: Open Link in new Tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, windows-phone-8

I have tried to achieve this in several ways, none of them work:

```
<a href="url" target="_blank"/>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(url)"/>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(url,'_blank')"/>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(url,'_newtab')"/>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(url,'popup','width=640,height=480')"/>
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201436/how-to-open-a-new-window-or-tab-via-javascript-in-windows-phone-7-browser) that this is not possible to control programmatically on Windows Phone 7, however I need a solution for Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1):

> There are some minor differences between Internet Explorer 10 for
>   Windows 8 and Internet Explorer 10 for Windows Phone that you need to
>   be aware of. Internet Explorer 10 for Windows Phone does not support
>   the following:
>
> - Cross-tab communication via script (as a result window.open opens the destination URL in the same tab)
> - Also in Internet Explorer 10 for Windows Phone, Window.open does not return a valid window object. This is because on the phone each
>     “window” is isolated in its own sandbox.

Quote from http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/08/internet-explorer-10-brings-html5-to-windows-phone-8-in-a-big-way.aspx - open the link for the full list.

Comment: Is there a workaround to verify if a new window can be opened so a fallback method can be used if not?

Answer (score 0):

While trying to find an answer to this I stumbled across a question that was already answered here on StackExchange. I own a Windows Phone and am a little saddened at the answer.

[How to open a new window or tab via javascript in windows phone 7 browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201436/how-to-open-a-new-window-or-tab-via-javascript-in-windows-phone-7-browser)

NOTE: I realize the question was on Windows Phone 8 and the answer is referring to Windows Phone 7, but I believe the answer is the same.