# Image link not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, image, mobile, hyperlink

I have images on a website that I have linking to other .html pages.

They are functioning on my computer but on my phone and tablet - touching the images does not link to the other .html pages.

```
<a target="_blank" href="global.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/portfolio/icon_global.jpg"/></a>
```

Here is the css class info:

```
.img-responsive { display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Comment: Are you using a windows phone? Some browsers on mobile phones do not support to open pages in new windows/tabs. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201436/how-to-open-a-new-window-or-tab-via-javascript-in-windows-phone-7-browser

Comment: Excellent, I just removed target="_blank" and now it's working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this...i have tried
it'll work..
 in some mobiles new tab open target="_blank" option will not work

`<a href="myfile.htm"><img src="rainbow.gif"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [dc.sashwat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003479/dc-sashwat)'s comment:

"Are you using a windows phone? Some browsers on mobile phones do not support to open pages in new windows/tabs"

---

I just removed target="_blank" and now it's working perfectly